# Form Submit using Jquery and mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Am trying to submit a form using jQuery. My code below

```
<form id="sampleForm" action="@Url.Action("submitSearch","Home")">
    //Form Fields  textbox
    <button id="test" type="submit" ></button>
</form>
```

Inside `document.ready` having script

```
$("#sampleForm").submit(function () {
    console.log("Success");
});
```

But when click sumbit nothing is happening.

I tried the below code to see if I have mapped correctly and that works fine

```
$(document).on("click", "#search-button", function () {
    console.log("Success");
});
```

What am missing while submitting form ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759004/submit-form-through-trigerring-jquery-submit-button-not-working

Comment: yes i upvoted laready

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$("#test").click(function(){
   $("#sampleForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: what the diff for click or submit ?

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible you're submitting but the page is reloading and the console log is cleared?

Also, just to clarify...

```
$("#sampleForm").submit(function () {
    console.log("Success");
});
```

This wires up an event to do stuff when the sampleForm is submitted...

```
$('#sampleForm').submit();
```

actually triggers the submit event

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

```
<input id="test" type="submit" ></input>
```

Instead of this

```
<button id="test" type="submit" ></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for tag `button`:

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

if you don't like or don't need put the text of button, and you only need run the event submit of a form, you cant do this:

html:

```
<form id="sampleForm" action="@Url.Action("submitSearch","Home")" method="get">
    //Form Fields  textbox
</form>
```

js:

```
// where needed
$('#sampleForm').submit();
// or
$('#sampleForm').trigger('submit');
```

but always you need put any tag input for compatibility with IE